Vue this.$emits suddenly stops working in the middle of a function call
I have this function that is supposed to emit updates to the parent component before and after it sends a request to the server.  I am using Vue to run the front end.  Here is the function I am having issues with:
    saveUpdates: async function () {
      const component = {
        doc: {
          specifications: this.edit_specs_buffer
        },
        component_id: this.id
      }
      this.req.upsertRecord('Components', component)

      this.$emit('toggleLoaded', false) // Does Execute // Does Execute
      const resp = await this.req.sendRequest(window.origin) // Does Execute
      this.$emit('refreshParent', true) // Does NOT Execute (This is broken)

      const createToast = this.$root.createToast // Does Execute
      resp.messages.flash.forEach(message => { // Does Execute
        createToast(message) // Does Execute
      })
      // Everything else works
      if (resp.status !== 201) {
        return false
      }
      this.req = new CustomRequest(this.$cookies.get('session'))
      return true
    },

After the await this.req.sendRequest line, this.$emit doesn't work at all.  I have tried fake functions that just send a console log to test if it's just the refreshParent emit that is the issue.  For some reason this.$emit completely stops working after the sendRequest call.
For additional reference, here is the child component in the parent component:
          <SpecificationsComponent
            :key="specs_key"
            :doc="component_data.doc"
            :spectype="'component'"
            :name="get_component_primary_name(component_data)"
            :id="component_data.component_id"
            v-on:edit-specs="(e) => edit_specs = e"
            v-on:toggle-loaded="toggleLoaded"
            v-on:refresh-parent="refreshParent"
          ></SpecificationsComponent>

  methods: {
    toggleLoaded: function (val) {
      this.loaded = val
    },
    refreshParent: function (val) {
      console.log('refreshing parent')
      console.log(val)

      // this is a fetch request that is suposed to fire after the
      // sendRequest finishes making changes to the server to update the
      // page with the most recent information.
      this.getComponentData()

    },

What confuses me the most is that this.$root works fine while this.$emit doesn't. Any ideas?
package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "7.12.1",
    "@dagrejs/dagre": "1.1.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "@vue-flow/background": "1.3.0",
    "@vue-flow/controls": "1.1.1",
    "@vue-flow/core": "1.36.0",
    "@vue-flow/minimap": "1.4.0",
    "@vue-flow/node-resizer": "1.3.6",
    "@vue-flow/node-toolbar": "1.1.0",
    "@vue/cli": "5.0.8",
    "@vue/compat": "3.4.30",
    "@vuelidate/core": "2.0.3",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "2.0.4",
    "bootstrap-vue": "npm:@ankurk91/bootstrap-vue@^3.0.2",
    "chartjs": "0.3.24",
    "core-js": "3.32.1",
    "jquery": "3.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "0.3.7",
    "popper.js": "1.16.1",
    "portal-vue": "2.1.7",
    "vue": "3.4.26",
    "vue-barcode-reader": "1.0.3",
    "vue-chartjs": "5.3.1",
    "vue-cookies": "1.8.3",
    "vue-qr-generator": "3.0.1",
    "vue-router": "4.3.2",
    "vue-select": "3.20.3",
    "vue3-easy-data-table": "1.5.47"
  },

I tried to figure out if there was something wrong with how I am calling and using async functions.  After fiddling with that for awhile, I realized all those async calls must be working because I am able to see the 201 response from the server indicating that the sendRequest function completed correctly and gave a finished output instead of a promise.
*EDIT
Here is the sendRequest function
async sendRequest (origin) {
    const fetchRequest = origin + '/api/v1/submit'
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log(
      'PUT ' + fetchRequest
    )

    const response = await fetch(fetchRequest, {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      body: JSON.stringify(this.compileRequest())
    })

    if (response.status === 201) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log('Request successful')
    } else {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log('Request failed')
    }

    const data = await response.json()
    data.status = response.status
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.log(data)
    return data
  }

I am not sure how I can make this reproducible.  There is so much other code going on with these Vue components.  Everything is a bit jumbled up as well.  If you have any advice on this matter I'll take it!

The question needs  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , How do you know that it "Does Execute" and "Does NOT Execute"? If you don't see an effect from the execution, that's another thing. this.req.sendRequest isn't shown, it's unknown how it can fail. "I am able to see the 201 response from the server " - see where? This should be unambiguously done, this can be done with a debugger, using console and indirect clues is the last resort.

I hope this edit can help @EstusFlask.

Try a debugger then. The most straightforward and failproof way is "debugger" statement. You need to verify on your side that this.$emit('refreshParent', true)  line is reached. Then the problem needs to be isolated to either vue event system or the execution of saveUpdates . I don't see reasons for sendRequest to produce pending promise that could cause this, but it's not evident that this.req.sendRequest exists at the time when saveUpdates runs, for instance. And it's unknown where saveUpdates is called and whether it's possible that the errors are suppressed.

Do you recomend any good debuggers for vue @EstusFlask?  I have had difficulty using debuggers for the client side portion of this app.

It's regular debugger in browser devtools, not specific to vue. Place debugger statements between lines of interest and they will work as breakpoints once devtools are open. It can be less than perfect if the project is badly configured, especially for async/await, make sure you have native async functions to debug them properly, transpilation target should be es2017 or higher

I wonder if my question is related to this question?  Im tagging people related to that question hoping to get their attention.  @AlexanderKim

Ok ill try that, Thank you @EstusFlask

Tagging people not involved in a discussion doesn't work on SO. In the linked question the reason is obvious, there's race condition with $on. There's no such clues in yours. Generally there are no valid reasons for one emitted event to work and another not, unless there's a bug in the framework, which is not impossible but unlikely. A possible clue is :key, is it there for a reason? If a component is unmounted in the middle of execution of saveUpdates, which is doable with both :key or v- directives it's usually used with, this would be the reason for emit to be ignored, the only valid one

The reason I had a key was to update the component after refreshParent is complete to refresh the child component with the updated data.  I removed it and I still have the issue however.  I used the debugger and discovered that emitting refreshparent after sendRequest works if emit('toggleLoaded') is commented out.  It seems that having two emits in relitively quick order is causing the second one to fail silently. @EstusFlask

Changing a key in this manner would lead to something you described. This results in the comp being remounted, while old instance is discarded. Make sure you removed :key in code you're debugging. "is causing the second one to fail" - I don't see a reason for this, it's more the effect of an emit (like changing a key) that could affect something. Any uncaught errors are generally supposed to be visible in console but as said, it's unknown how saveUpdates is called and what happens with the errors. Use try..catch inside saveUpdates to make sure. There are not much possibilities at this point

I think I finally solved it....kinda.
Big thanks to Estus Flask for helping me out on this one.
Unfortunatly I still don't know exaclty why I am seeing this beheivor with my code.  I went through debuggers trying to identify exaclty what was causing this and I came up with nothing.  At some point I just started moving things around in a despirete attempt to get it working the way I wanted it to and somehow I found a solution.
    saveUpdates: async function () {
      const component = {
        doc: {
          specifications: this.edit_specs_buffer
        },
        component_id: this.id
      }
      this.req.upsertRecord('Components', component)

      const resp = await this.req.sendRequest(window.origin)
      this.$emit('toggleLoaded', false)
      this.$emit('refreshParent')

      const createToast = this.$root.createToast
      resp.messages.flash.forEach(message => {
        createToast(message)
      })
      // Everything else works
      if (resp.status !== 201) {
        return false
      }
      this.req = new CustomRequest(this.$cookies.get('session'))
      return true
    }

Arranging the code this way gave me the exact behavior I wanted. After clicking the save button, the parent component hides everything and displays a loading screen, then the toast is shown with a success message, then the new updated data is fetched again and displayed after the get request finishes.
